# R urlquery in Japanese. Encoding issue?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to read the following CSV file containing Japanese and English text in R, construct a URL and retrieve the results.

The data looks like this;

```
ID,AutoG1,AutoG2
8756,Pocket Card,ポケットカード
4574,Takara Standard,タカラスタンダード
```

And the code I am trying to run is as follows;

```
>library(XML)
>library(RCurl)
>
>data<-read.csv("test.csv")
>url <- paste("suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=jp&qu=",data[1,"AutoG2"],sep="")
>url
"suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=jp&qu=ポケットカード"
>result <-getURL(URLencode(url),.opts=opts)
>doc <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(result))
>length(zzdoc)
0
```

The results should look like [**this**](http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=jp&qu=%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89), which shows that there are in fact 10 results.

I think one clue to resolving this is to understand how the url variable is represented internally. If I use the URL string directly;

```
>url2 <- "suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=jp&qu=ポケットカード"
>zz <-getURL(URLencode(url2),.opts=opts)
>zzdoc <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(zz))
>length(zzdoc)
10
```

I get the desired result, but i need to get these results programmatically using something like the first code fragment. url and url2 look similar but internally they are different, which I think is due to the encoding.

```
>url==url2
FALSE
>Encoding(url)
"unknown"
>Encoding(url2)
"UTF-8"
```

I have tried to force the encoding thus;

```
> Encoding(url)<-"UTF-8"
> url
"suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=jp&qu=\u0083|\u0083P\u0083b\u0083g\u0083J\u0081[\u0083h"
> zz <-getURL(URLencode(url),.opts=opts)
Warning message:
In strsplit(URL, "") : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
```

which does not seem to work either.
Can anyone provide any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the "http://" You code works with

```
url <- paste("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=jp&qu=",data[1,"AutoG2"],sep="")
```

For reference the Nippon package is great for switching encodings